# Can't process class (Unknown verification type [19] in stack map frame)

Tags: java, android, proguard

I got such problem while release Android project after importing SDK for card reader payments:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>    java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/denys/Android/Titovskiy_S-epos-623918383149/app/libs/PMCore.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Can't process class [com/imagpay/bU.class] (Unknown verification type [19] in stack map frame))

A problem occurred only in release mode. `bU.class is` from **SDK package**.

Have any idea to fix it?

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: I just switched off ProGuard :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109942/545127