# java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 421

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, jaxws-maven-plugin

I get following error when I try to deploy a war file.

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 421


Exception Details:
  Location:
    it/codegen/tbx/search/service/TravelBoxSearch.convertQuoteItemsEx(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Lit/codegen/CGError; @421: getstatic
  Reason:
    Type 'it/codegen/CGResponse' (current frame, locals[5]) is not assignable to 'it/codegen/CGError' (stack map, locals[5])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @58
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/TravelBoxSearch', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/List', 'it/codegen/logging/TimeLogger', 'it/codegen/CGResponse', 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/ShoppingBasket' }
    stack: { 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/ShoppingBasket' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @421
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/TravelBoxSearch', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/List', 'it/codegen/logging/TimeLogger', 'it/codegen/CGError', 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/ShoppingBasket' }
    stack: { }

  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 013a 04b2 0127 9900 15bb 01a4 59b8 01a5
    0x0000010: b601 a6b8 01a7 b701 a83a 04b8 0222 2cb6
    0x0000020: 0223 bb07 d759 1402 1213 07d8 b707 d93a
    0x0000030: 052a 2cb7 02b0 3a06 1906 c601 6b19 06b6
    0x0000040: 02b1 3a07 1907 c601 452d c601 272d b902
    0x0000050: 4e01 009a 011e bb01 cc59 b701 cd3a 082d
    0x0000060: b902 3201 003a 0919 09b9 0233 0100 9900
    0x0000070: 4a19 09b9 0234 0100 c002 353a 0a19 0ac6
    0x0000080: 0036 190a b602 3ac6 002e 1908 bb00 3f59
    0x0000090: b700 4019 0ab6 023a b602 a4b6 0042 190a
    0x00000a0: b602 3ab6 023b b602 4cb6 0043 190a b602
    0x00000b0: 3ab6 011d 57a7 ffb2 1907 b603 cfc6 0079
    0x00000c0: 1907 b603 cfb9 0232 0100 3a09 1909 b902
    0x00000d0: 3301 0099 0063 1909 b902 3401 00c0 02cf
    0x00000e0: 3a0a 190a c600 4f19 08bb 003f 59b7 0040
    0x00000f0: 190a b604 1db6 0042 190a b605 81b6 024c
    0x0000100: b600 43b6 01e0 9900 2d19 08bb 003f 59b7
    0x0000110: 0040 190a b604 1db6 0042 190a b605 81b6
    0x0000120: 024c b600 43b6 01e1 c007 c819 0ab6 07da
    0x0000130: b607 dba7 ff99 2a2b 2db6 07c7 3a09 1909
    0x0000140: b602 8599 002b b200 29b8 0038 b200 3913
    0x0000150: 07dc b600 3b2a 1909 1907 1906 b707 dd3a
    0x0000160: 0519 0619 05b6 02ac c002 adb6 02c4 a700
    0x0000170: 34b2 0029 b800 38b2 0039 1307 deb6 003b
    0x0000180: 1905 1307 dfb6 027a a700 1ab2 0029 b800
    0x0000190: 38b2 0039 1307 e0b6 003b 1905 1307 e1b6
    0x00001a0: 027a a700 1ab2 0029 b800 38b2 0039 1303
    0x00001b0: feb6 003b 1905 1307 e2b6 027a 1905 3a07
    0x00001c0: b201 2799 0008 1904 b601 b619 07b0 3a0b
    0x00001d0: b201 2799 0008 1904 b601 b619 0bbf     
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [27, 448] => handler: 462
    bci [462, 464] => handler: 462
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@27,Object[#3374])
    full_frame(@103,{Object[#3339],Object[#3359],Object[#3359],Object[#3375],Object[#3374],Object[#3451],Object[#3623],Object[#3624],Object[#3478],Object[#3480]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@181)
    chop_frame(@184,1)
    append_frame(@204,Object[#3480])
    same_frame_extended(@307)
    chop_frame(@310,1)
    chop_frame(@366,1)
    same_frame(@369)
    same_frame(@395)
    chop_frame(@418,1)
    same_frame(@421)
    same_frame(@444)
    append_frame(@459,Object[#3451])
    full_frame(@462,{Object[#3339],Object[#3359],Object[#3359],Object[#3375],Object[#3374]},{Object[#3344]})
    full_frame(@475,{Object[#3339],Object[#3359],Object[#3359],Object[#3375],Object[#3374],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#3344]},{})

java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 421
Exception Details:
  Location:
    it/codegen/tbx/search/service/TravelBoxSearch.convertQuoteItemsEx(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Lit/codegen/CGError; @421: getstatic
  Reason:
    Type 'it/codegen/CGResponse' (current frame, locals[5]) is not assignable to 'it/codegen/CGError' (stack map, locals[5])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @58
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/TravelBoxSearch', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/List', 'it/codegen/logging/TimeLogger', 'it/codegen/CGResponse', 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/ShoppingBasket' }
    stack: { 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/ShoppingBasket' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @421
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/TravelBoxSearch', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/List', 'it/codegen/logging/TimeLogger', 'it/codegen/CGError', 'it/codegen/tbx/search/service/ShoppingBasket' }
    stack: { }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 013a 04b2 0127 9900 15bb 01a4 59b8 01a5
    0x0000010: b601 a6b8 01a7 b701 a83a 04b8 0222 2cb6
    0x0000020: 0223 bb07 d759 1402 1213 07d8 b707 d93a
    0x0000030: 052a 2cb7 02b0 3a06 1906 c601 6b19 06b6
    0x0000040: 02b1 3a07 1907 c601 452d c601 272d b902
    0x0000050: 4e01 009a 011e bb01 cc59 b701 cd3a 082d
    0x0000060: b902 3201 003a 0919 09b9 0233 0100 9900
    0x0000070: 4a19 09b9 0234 0100 c002 353a 0a19 0ac6
    0x0000080: 0036 190a b602 3ac6 002e 1908 bb00 3f59
    0x0000090: b700 4019 0ab6 023a b602 a4b6 0042 190a
    0x00000a0: b602 3ab6 023b b602 4cb6 0043 190a b602
    0x00000b0: 3ab6 011d 57a7 ffb2 1907 b603 cfc6 0079
    0x00000c0: 1907 b603 cfb9 0232 0100 3a09 1909 b902
    0x00000d0: 3301 0099 0063 1909 b902 3401 00c0 02cf
    0x00000e0: 3a0a 190a c600 4f19 08bb 003f 59b7 0040
    0x00000f0: 190a b604 1db6 0042 190a b605 81b6 024c
    0x0000100: b600 43b6 01e0 9900 2d19 08bb 003f 59b7
    0x0000110: 0040 190a b604 1db6 0042 190a b605 81b6
    0x0000120: 024c b600 43b6 01e1 c007 c819 0ab6 07da
    0x0000130: b607 dba7 ff99 2a2b 2db6 07c7 3a09 1909
    0x0000140: b602 8599 002b b200 29b8 0038 b200 3913
    0x0000150: 07dc b600 3b2a 1909 1907 1906 b707 dd3a
    0x0000160: 0519 0619 05b6 02ac c002 adb6 02c4 a700
    0x0000170: 34b2 0029 b800 38b2 0039 1307 deb6 003b
    0x0000180: 1905 1307 dfb6 027a a700 1ab2 0029 b800
    0x0000190: 38b2 0039 1307 e0b6 003b 1905 1307 e1b6
    0x00001a0: 027a a700 1ab2 0029 b800 38b2 0039 1303
    0x00001b0: feb6 003b 1905 1307 e2b6 027a 1905 3a07
    0x00001c0: b201 2799 0008 1904 b601 b619 07b0 3a0b
    0x00001d0: b201 2799 0008 1904 b601 b619 0bbf     
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [27, 448] => handler: 462
    bci [462, 464] => handler: 462
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@27,Object[#3374])
    full_frame(@103,{Object[#3339],Object[#3359],Object[#3359],Object[#3375],Object[#3374],Object[#3451],Object[#3623],Object[#3624],Object[#3478],Object[#3480]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@181)
    chop_frame(@184,1)
    append_frame(@204,Object[#3480])
    same_frame_extended(@307)
    chop_frame(@310,1)
    chop_frame(@366,1)
    same_frame(@369)
    same_frame(@395)
    chop_frame(@418,1)
    same_frame(@421)
    same_frame(@444)
    append_frame(@459,Object[#3451])
    full_frame(@462,{Object[#3339],Object[#3359],Object[#3359],Object[#3375],Object[#3374]},{Object[#3344]})
    full_frame(@475,{Object[#3339],Object[#3359],Object[#3359],Object[#3375],Object[#3374],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#3344]},{})

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:615)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And following is thek compiler that I use to compile the code

```
<plugin>            

    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>${testCompile.enable}</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
        <testSource>1.8</testSource>
        <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
        <!--<testExcludes>-->
            <!--<exclude>**/test/*.java</exclude>-->
        <!--</testExcludes>-->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please have look and reply, sorry I'm not a expert with formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a much effort I found the issue. There was duplicate classes for CGError and CGResponse in two different libraries. So I guess the ones that were used in the compile time may differ to ones loaded in running time. Anyhow resolving the duplicate classes did the trick, and resolved this issue.

PS: don't wast time on -XX:-UseSplitVerifier configuration to fix this issue if you are on Java 1.8, even if you are on Java 1.7 try to avoid using that configuration as much as possible. Please go through following URL in order get a better understanding about the issue:

[What is a stack map frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109942)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue related to javassist verison and I reported in thread [Error mocking Class which hold reference to SQLiteOpenHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768644/error-mocking-class-which-hold-reference-to-sqliteopenhelper/53759201#53759201)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using OpenJDK Java versions, in my case the cause of this issue was the fact that I had an instanceof check inside a ternary statement. Once I replaced it with a proper if-else statement this error went away. When I set it back to ternary the error returned. My JRE is 8.0.212.03-hotspot for reference.

I'm also using Nashorn, I don't know if that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using Eclipse jee 2019-12-R. Changing Eclipse version fixed it.